# angular ng-include not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

The is a part of my html where I am trying to include the another HTML file "content.html" but it is not working. Those addresses in the source are correct but still I am not able to make it happen.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>

   <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Your page title here :)</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
 <!-- Scripts
 –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js\jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div ng-include src="'content.html'"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

and this is my content.html

```
  <div class="container">
  <h1>Heading!</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add `ng-app=""` to your page `html` tag, so that angular will get kick off on the page. After that will start traversing the page & will collect all directive & it will compile them.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="">
```

Instead of `ng-include` with `src` you could directly pass template value in `ng-include` attribute as well.

```
<div ng-include="'content.html'">
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/YAhYgd7RyZeGA03fpT6L?p=preview)

Comment: Don't you also need to use it as `ng-include="'content.html'"` when using it as an attribute? Isn't `src` only valid when using `ng-include` as an element?

Comment: @Lex Thanks for heads up, will add it in answer as an improvement , Thanks :)